# how to upload multiple files to azure blob storage using azure machine Learning

Tags: file, azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

I have come across a requirement wherein the first part involves reading a blob file (i.e. .csv) present in Azure blob storage and splitting the file data into multiple files, based on the distinct combination of few columns. The second part of the requirement involves writing/uploading the multiple files to Azure blob Storage at a separate destination folder.

I am able to split the blob file into multiple files, but am not able to write/upload the partitioned files on to azure blob storage. Is there any possibility to write the files to blob storage. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered having an Azure Data Factory pipeline that triggers the ML experiment on schedule. This can be used to create multiple output files and output them to blob. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities
You could try and have multiple containers to store your output: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage
Regards,
Jaya